# Spring JPA + Hibernate XML Configuration

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, jpa, configuration

Recently, I started to learn Spring JPA and I get confused on setup the Spring JPA in xml configuration.

I googled the spring documentation site, and not much I can get from there. I googled some examples to setup Spring JPA, but the samples do not give any detail explanation on beans and property used in it.

They also use different approaches like in one example, it use org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource and the second one use org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.
In one example, it defines jpaVendorAdapter property but the other one do not define it.

I just one to know the best way to setup Spring JPA configuration in XML using Hibernate as its provider.

Please help me guys, thanks!

Comment: have you checked this example, it explains everything you need. https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-jpa-examples

Answer (score 0):

please find configuration in below

```
<jdbc:embedded-database type="H2" id="dataSource">
</jdbc:embedded-database>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:packagesToScan="org.spring.web.example.domain">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean id="jpaAdapter"
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                p:generateDdl="true" p:showSql="true" p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

this configuration is define data source on embedded database you can change it to be on any database you are prefer then it is define entityManagerFactory to be used in jpa DAOs as

```
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}
@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

check [link](http://hop2croft.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/jpa-basic-example-with-entitymanager-spring-and-maven/)

for me currently I'm using spring-Data JpaRepository instead of creating DAO from scratch,

and if you want to add transaction use :

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

then you can use @Transaction

also check this [channel](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7350712B99EFC5DD)